# C#. задание на массивы

Tags: c#, массивы

```
`using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // your code goes here
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i,j, n,t, sum;
            string spisok;
            int[] a = new int[1000];
            n = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text);
            spisok = "";
            listBox1.Text = "";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
            {
                a[i] = rnd.Next(-100, 100);
                spisok = spisok + Convert.ToString(i) + ")" + Convert.ToString(a[i]) + "" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            label3.Text = spisok;
            for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
                if (a[j]) > a[j + 1];
            { t = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = t;
        }
```

}`задание:После каждой пары элементов массива А(n), расположенных в порядке возрастания, вставить их сумму.
Я пыталась сначала выставить по возрастанию, и то ошибка, и не знаю как вставить сумму посл каждого 2-го.
[image]

Comment: Вот и смотрите сами свои скриншоты.

Comment: я добавила,то что у меня было на скрине,  буду благодарна если вы мне поможете)

Answer (score -1):

Что касается подсвеченной в редакторе ошибки. Посмотрите на свой первый цикл `for` как на образец и сделайте так же во втором цикле. Аргументы цикла надо разделять знаками `;`, а не `,`.

По сути же вопроса из вашего кода достаточно трудно понять, что вы вообще делаете. Приведите сначала код в виде текста, причём компилируемого.

P.S. Алгоритм вставки элемента в массив можете прочитать, например, [здесь](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-how-to-insert-an-element-in-an-array/). Если вы уверены, что выделенного под массив места вам хватит даже с учётом вставок, то можно не создавать новый массив, а просто копировать на один элемент вправо "хвост" массива правее вставляемого элемента (копировать причём нужно от последних элементов к первым) и затем присваивать новый элемент массива в образовавшуюся свободную ячейку.

Comment: @Катя Плечистова В рамках одного массива сделать это не так просто, а вот с использованием второго - гораздо проще.

Comment: Подскажите как под мое задание сделать код?